# REDUCE ERRORS can some one help me with this lex and grammer code

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc, lex

This is my grammar:

```
%% Start : _PROGRAM _ID _SEMI Block
Block : Declarations BlockStatements
Declarations : _VAR _LPAREN VariableDeclarions _SEMI _RPAREN _ADD 
               | ;
VariableDeclarions : _ID _LPAREN _COMMA _ID _RPAREN _MULT _COLON TypeSpec
TypeSpec : _INTEGER 
           | _REAL
BlockStatements : _BEGIN Statements _END 
                  | ;
Statements : Assignment W 
             | ;
W : Statements
Statement : Assignment 
            | ;
Assignment : _ID _ASSIGN Expr _SEMI
Expr : Term _LPAREN _ADD Term _RPAREN _MULT 
       | Term _LPAREN _SUB Term _RPAREN _MULT 
       | Term _LPAREN _MULT 
       | Term _LPAREN _DIV _RPAREN _MULT
Term : _CONST 
       | _LPAREN Expr _RPAREN 
       | _ID
```

I'm getting error like: 
2 rules never reduced.

Can someone help me figure out the problem?

I'm unable to correct the grammar.

Comment: Please add the actual error message that you're getting.

Comment: 2 rules never reduced

Comment: Unrelated. Token names become symbols -- `enum` members, if you're using flex -- in the C program, so they need to conform to C naming rules. And C naming rules reserve all names starting with an underscore and a capital letter, so using those names is Undefined Behaviour by the C standard. If you don't want to just use the words, which is the usual convention, you can dress them up with a prefix like `T_` or `TOK_`, rather than just an single underscore.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your grammar through `bison` (after adding the missing `%token` definitions), I get the following output:

```
bla.y: warning: 1 nonterminal useless in grammar [-Wother]
bla.y: warning: 2 rules useless in grammar [-Wother]
bla.y:17.1-9: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: Statement [-Wother]
 Statement : Assignment
```

So according to the last part of the output, `Statement` is the one that's useless. So let's look at where `Statement` is used in the grammar: it isn't. You define `Statement`, but you never use it anywhere. So that's why it's useless and why you get that warning.